# Search in array and set value

Tags: php, arrays

How can I set value (1, for example) for a key `who_use` where `user_id` = 765754346?

And how to get a value of `shop_name` where `user_id` = 123456789;

I tried `array_filter` but haven't any idea how to do this.

```
array (
  'igive' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'name' => 'Alex',
      'shop_name' => 'Shop1',
      'rights' => 'admin',
      'who_use' => '',
      'user_id' => '765754346',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'name' => 'Dmitry',
      'shop_name' => 'Shop2',
      'rights' => 'manager',
      'who_use' => '',
      'user_id' => '123456789',
    ),
  ),
  'giventome' => 
  array (
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can approach this using `array_walk`

/*How can i set value (1, for example) for a key 'who_use' where 'user_id' = 765754346?*/

```
$user_id = '765754346';
array_walk($arr['igive'], function($v, $k) use (&$arr, $user_id){
  ($arr['igive'][$k]['user_id'] == $user_id) ? ($arr['igive'][$k]['who_use'] = 1) : '';
});
```

[Live Demo](https://3v4l.org/P8L79)

/*how to get a value of 'shop_nam'e where 'user_id' = 123456789;*/

```
$user_id = '765754346';
$shop_name = '';
array_walk($arr['igive'], function($v, $k) use (&$shop_name, $user_id){
    ($v['user_id'] == $user_id) ? ($shop_name = $v['shop_name']) : '';
}); 
echo $shop_name;
```

[Live Demo](https://3v4l.org/Be4Ab)

Comment: I think you should also include the simple `foreach` way

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to access the data on a regular basis, it may be better to convert the array so that it is indexed by `user_id` using `array_column()` and you can then just directly access each piece of data as you need it...

```
$baseData = array (
    'igive' =>
    array (
        0 =>
        array (
            'name' => 'Alex',
            'shop_name' => 'Shop1',
            'rights' => 'admin',
            'who_use' => '',
            'user_id' => '765754346',
        ),
        1 =>
        array (
            'name' => 'Dmitry',
            'shop_name' => 'Shop2',
            'rights' => 'manager',
            'who_use' => '',
            'user_id' => '123456789',
        ),
    ),
    'giventome' =>
    array (
    ),
);

$data = array_column($baseData['igive'], null, "user_id");

// For who_use...
echo $data['765754346']['who_use'].PHP_EOL;
// For shop_name...
echo $data['123456789']['shop_name'].PHP_EOL;
```